# Split large text file (5 million records) into smaller files in parallel using threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, .net-framework-version

I have a large text file containing 5 million of records (5 columns and 5 million rows). The image of file is shown below

[image: Large text file to be split]

For splitting, I used the concept of threading. I created 10 threads for splitting the larger file. I have used the string array to store the values while reading the larger file. The code is shown below.

```
class Program
{
    const string sourceFileName = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\ThreadingExp\NewMarketData.txt";
    const string destinationFileName = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\ThreadingExp\NewMarketData-Part-{0}.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] index = new int[20];
        index[0] = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<11;i++)
        {
            index[i] = index[i-1]+500000;
        }

        //Reading Part
        var sourceFile = new StreamReader(sourceFileName);
        string[] ListLines = new string[5000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            ListLines[i] = sourceFile.ReadLine();
        }            

        //Creating array of threads
        Thread[] ArrayofThreads = new Thread[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayofThreads.Length; i++)
        {
            ArrayofThreads[i] = new Thread(() => Writing(ListLines,index[i], index[i+1]));
            ArrayofThreads[i].Start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayofThreads.Length; i++)
        {
            ArrayofThreads[i].Join();
        }
    }
    static void Writing(string[] array, int a, int b)
    {
        //Getting the thread number
        int id= Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        var destinationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(destinationFileName,id));

        string line;
        for (int i = a; i< b;i++ )
        {
            line = array[i];
            destinationFile.WriteLine(line);
        }

        destinationFile.Close();         
    }

}
```

The code works fine. Writing to different files is done in parallel here. But for reading, I have stored the whole content in a single array and then pass through different threads for writing using indexing. I want to do both the tasks (read the larger file and write in the different small files) in parallel using threads.

Comment: You can use Tasks instead of threads to let the TPL determine the optimal execution plan (this is done dynamically so it will perform good on different machines). tell me if you want an example

Comment: yeah..it will be better if you could provide some examples for better understanding.

Comment: see an example below

Comment: Unless you read from one physical disk and write to another physical disk running reading and writing jobs in parallel will most likely decrease performance due to higher IO load on a single disk.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost certainly better off doing this with a single thread.

First, you *must* read the text file sequentially. There's no shortcut that will let you skip ahead and find the 500,000th line without first reading the 499,999 lines that come before it.

Second, even if you could do that, the disk drive can only service a single request at a time. It can't be reading from two places at the same time. So while you're reading one part of the file, the thread that wants to read another part of the file is just sitting there waiting for the disk drive.

Finally, unless your output files are on separate drives, you have the same problem as with reading: the disk drive can only do one thing at a time.

So you're better off to start with something simple:

```
const int maxLinesPerFile = 5000000;
int fileNumber = 0;
var destinationFile = File.CreateText("outputFile"+fileNumber);

int linesRead = 0;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(inputFile))
{
    ++linesRead;
    if (linesRead > maxLinesPerFile)
    {
        destinationFile.Close();
        ++fileNumber;
        destinationFile = File.CreateText("outputFile"+fileNumber);
    }
    destinationFile.WriteLine(line);
}
destinationFile.Close();
```

If your input and output files are on separate drives, you could potentially save a little bit of time by having two threads: one for input and one for output. They would communicate using a `BlockingCollection`. Basically, the input thread would put lines onto the queue and the output thread would read from the queue and output the files. In theory that will overlap the reading time with the writing time, but the truth is that the queue fills up and the reader ends up having to wait on the writing thread. You get *some* increase in performance, but not nearly what you'd expect.

Comment: I have already tried this way and it works fine. It uses single thread and doesn't perform the desired tasks in parallel. It uses the looping. But, I wanted to do the reading and writing tasks in parallel. So, i thought if i could use the concept of threading in this.  Thanks

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Did you read the part where I point out that multiple threads probably won't make it any faster, and explain why?